# Android: How to get arrow button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, google-translate

I would love to have the arrow button, which is used in google translate, in my app.
The one used on the right of the textview here:

[image]

In which way could I get it with the least loss of quality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `<HTML><BODY>&#8594;` (just a WAG that Android components will render HTML).

Comment: use ImageButton instead of Button. here is the pack of standard Icon: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can download a pack of Android ActionBar icons [here](https://design.google.com/icons), and the forward arrow is there also. Hope this helps.

Comment: link broken (to the material design icons)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look in the SDK. The SDK has pretty much all the default icons for Android. You can find it in `[ANDROID_SDK_HOME]/platforms/[ANDROID_VERSION]/data/res/`

Look in all `drawable-xxxx` folders (i.e. drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc...) for the icon

Comment: It was there, but unfortunately in not so good quality. However thanks for the answer and +1

Comment: What kind of quality are you looking for? The icons in there are the exact ones Android uses. If the icon is going to be used in your Android app then there is no difference between the ones in that folder and the ones you see on the translate app.

Comment: Good point, but in my app, the arrow must be bigger than usual, so I'm looking for a bit more pixels than usual.

Answer (score 2):

As [Egor pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648685/2538037), the arrows can be found in the official [Android Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html). Here are the paths:

### Holo Light (Black arrows):

**Arrow back:**
`Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons\holo_light\02_navigation_back\`

**Arrow forward:**
`Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons\holo_light\02_navigation_forward\`

### Holo Dark (White arrows):

**Arrow back:**
`Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons\holo_dark\02_navigation_back\`

**Arrow forward:**
`Android Design - Icons 20131120\Action Bar Icons\holo_dark\02_navigation_forward\`