# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled showing an arrow instead of left caret

Tags: android

I want to show a Up button in my activity, the functionality is working fine, but am unable to get the left caret to show. It instead shows an ugly back arrow. I am doing this in my activity -

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.second));
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    ....
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ....

   }
}
```

But I am only seeing this -

[image: Back Arrow]

This is the layout xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.step.main.SecondActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listsecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:context=".SecondActivity"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any suggestions? Also, is there a way to change the color of back button be white?

Note: I am using theme - `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Can you show your `toolbar` xml?

Comment: Added the layout xml above.

Comment: Take a look at this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: None of them have worked for me.

Comment: Ahh, just figured it out.  You just need to call `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator ( R.drawable.your_custom_image);`  I was able to get it to show `ic_launcher` when I tested it.  Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778278/how-to-change-homeasup-indicator-in-new-appcompat-toolbar

Comment: is there any drawable image for showing left caret?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788464/how-to-change-color-of-the-back-arrow-in-the-new-material-theme/26837072#26837072), you can make any icon show up as white.

As for the left carat icon, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648495/android-how-to-get-arrow-button/29075006#29075006), which describes where to find it in the [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) which you will need to download.

Edit:  The icons you want are located in `Action Bar Icons/holo_dark/02_navigation_previous_item/`

For showing the left arrow white, you would do this:

```
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Add the following code to make the up arrow white:
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Note that you'll need to add these imports:

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
```

Comment: This works for changing the color to white. But my major issue is showing left caret. Is there any pre-specified drawable for that or do I need to create my own?

Comment: @Sam I just updated the answer, download the Action Bar Icon Pack,, and the linked answer explains where to find them.  http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: I downloaded and added ic_action_previous_item from holo_dark theme from the action pack which is the white image. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam  I saw that too.  Updated the answer, just in case this can help other people in the future!